# How to write conditionally path based htaccess rewrite to specific php file

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

My requirement is that when a request came `{{host}}/t1/batch` that time it should read from batch.php else any request should read from index.php. My base dir is `t1`. I am doing some experiment in htaccess. I am missing proper regular expression.

```
RewriteBase /t1
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(batch|index)/?$ $1.php [L,NC]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `t1` is a sub-directory of your document root, in `/t1/.htaccess` put this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /t1/
# no rewrites for real files and directories
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [NS,L]
# batch
RewriteRule ^batch(?=$|/) $0.php [NS,L]
# everything else
RewriteRule ^(?!index\.php$). index.php [NS,L]
```

If you have any rewriting in `/.htaccess`, as well, you will need to ignore the `t1` sub-directory in that file with a rule like:

```
RewriteRule ^t1(?:$|/) - [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved with the following rules:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/t1/batch/$
RewriteRule ^.*$ %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/batch.php [L,NC,END]
RewriteRule ^.*$ %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/index.php
```

I do not see the need for `RewriteBase` here.

Answer (score 0):

You can get it done with the following lines:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/t1/batch/?$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ batch.php [L,NC]
```

If you have `batch.php` under `t1` directory and the path is like `http://{host}/t1/batch.php`, you need to add RewriteBase line:

```
RewriteBase /t1
```

If you're not going to add RewriteBase line, you will have to follow absolute path like:

```
RewriteRule ^.*$ /t1/batch.php [L,NC]
```

Hope you understand and got the solution.